# R installed both 32bit and 64bit on my computer Do I need both?

Tags: r, rstudio

When I installed R both 32 bit and 64 bit were installed onto my computer. I also have rstudio installed. Can I delete the 32bit to open up more memory on my computer? Second part of question is how to check/change the R that rstudio links to?

Comment: In RStudio, it is the first field in `tools > global options`. RStudio uses 64 bit by default (unless you specify or you downloaded 32 bit RStudio). And yes you can delete the 32 bit one if you don't use it.

Comment: I suggest you don't delete, but modify the install to only install x64. Simply deleting the installation folder will leave behind spurious registry entries. But you certainly don't need both. You can safely uninstall the 32-bit installation.